# try to add a new column as foreign key in existing table with data and existing data manipulation

Tags: sql-server, database, api, database-design, database-schema

A very simple example. I have web API with  a table in the database

```
Employees
---------
Id
---------
Name
```

and for example, I have 50 records.

Now I have to Implement a feature to add extra info about the department. Because I have one to many relationships the new database schema is with department id

```
Employees           Department
----------         -----------
Id                  Id
---------           -----------
Name                Name
--------- 
DepartmentId
```

for this, I run the query (i use SQL server)

```
alter table Employees add constraint fk_employees_departmentid
foreign key (DepartmentId) references Department(Id);
```

But now I have some issues to handle

1)Now I have the 50 existing records without departmentId. However, I must add manually this value? What is the best practice? For 50 records it is possible but for 2000 records and more?

2) when I add departmentId column I set this column to have null values(is correct?), but as a foreign key, I don't want to allow null values. Can I change it or how can I handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1)Now I have the 50 existing records without departmentId. However, I must add manually this value? What is the best practice? For 50 records it is possible but for 2000 records and more?

It depends. You could set up a new department for "unassigned" and assign them all to that; you could send out a spreadsheet to HR saying *"the following employees don't have an assigned department; what department are they in? ps; don't remove the EmployeeID column from the sheet before you send it back; i need it to update the DB"*. It's very much a business contextual question, not a technical one. X thousand records is easy to handle.. It'll just take a bit of time to work through if you (or someone else) is doing it manually. This information is likely to be available somewhere else; you could perhaps send a list out to all department heads saying *"are any of these guys yours? Please remove all the names you don't have in your team from this spreadsheet and send it back to me"* then update the DB based on what you get back

As this is a one time operation you don't need anything particularly whizz for it - you can just get your Excel sheet back and in an empty column put:

```
="UPDATE emp SET departmentID = 5 WHERE id = " & A1
```

And fill it down to generate a bunch of update statements, copy the text into your query tool and hit go; don't need to get all fancy loading the sheet into a table, doing update joins etc - just hacky style sling together something in excel that will write the SQL for you, copy/paste/run. If HR have sent back the sheet with a list of department names, then put the dept name and id somewhere else on the sheet and use [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) or  [XLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929) to turn the name into the department number, then compose your SQL based on that

> 2) when I add departmentId column I set this column to have null values(is correct?), but as a foreign key, I don't want to allow null values. Can I change it or how can I handle it?

Foreign keyed columns are allowed to have NULL values - it isn't the FK that imposes a "No Nulls" restriction, it's the nullability of the column (alter the column to `departmantid INT NOT NULL`) that imposes that. A FK references a primary key and the primary key may not be null (or in some DB, at most one record can have a [partly] null PK), but you could just leave those departments null. If you do alter the column to be not null, you'll need to correct the NULL values first or the change will fail